# Calculating the Hedge Ratio

Tags: hedging, index, optimal-hedge-ratio, nonlinear

Suppose we have an index whose value is calculated by a weighted geometric mean. Now we want to recreate the index using its underlying components. How would we go about calculating the hedge ratios for the underlying components? Would the hedge ratios be dynamic?